# Magento admin panel throws and Error in Chrome while running correctly in Firefox?

Tags: php, magento

I am working with magneto. I open the link Catelog->Manage Categories. This link open the add category form. It seems to be working fine in the Mozilla Firefox. But when i open the same into the chrome page open for a short time and ajax loader shown. Once the loader closed it throws an error. Please see the attached images. I am unable to get the point.

Google Chrome Screen Shot

[image]

Mozilla Firefox Screen Shot
[image]

Comment: That is way to few information to really help you. I've seen such an output once where I had `var_dump()` debug output that was send through an AJAX response.

Comment: Thanks, @feeela. Could you elaborate a little bit more please.

Comment: how and where do you use jquery loader? show us the line `<script scr="your jquery loader path and name">`

Comment: @Amir Why do you assume, that jQuery is in use at some point? By default Magento still uses script.aculo.us.

Comment: @NitinKumarSoni First check your AJAX responses and see if they return valid HTML or JSON data – which depends on what is expected at the current point. As I said, you need to describe, which steps have led to this error and if there are any outputs, e.g. in the Chrom console

Comment: Thanks @feemla. Problem is solved now.

Comment: Thanks everyone. For your comments